# facing problem to show the message in toast

Tags: android

Hello i am using [this](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2010/05/04/android-webview-and-the-indeterminant-progress-solution/) tutorial to set the spinwheel for my webview , its working perfectly after removing this line

`Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and the errot is on `actitvity` ,

plus i would like to know that if there is no internet connection how we can set the message in this toast

Comment: What is the error? Got a log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the url example you have to write

```
//Main.java
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//this is also correct
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For [internet connectivity checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753412/android-internet-connectivity-check-problem)

Answer (score 3):

That first parameter in `makeText()` should be a `Context`.  I'm assuming what the author of the tutorial meant by `activity` was a non-static reference to the `Activity` class in which you're programming.  You would correctly reference it with something like

```
//MyActivity.java

Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Oh no!" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Oh no!" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

otherwise you can also use

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```