# Android - check for internet connection, and auto connect

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that works with data from the internet. For ease of usage, i want my app to check for established internet connection (described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753412/android-internet-connectivity-check-problem) topic), and automatically connect user's phone if no connection is active.
Is there a way my app could connect phone to the internet, or at least enable user to connect by "one click" (some sort of "this app is trying to connect to the internet - allow, deny" dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a message dialog and tell them that your action will use their internet connection. Don't reinvent the wheel, they're probably already connected to their preferred connection.

If you're doing something that requires a lot of data (downloading a big file or something), just warn them before hand so they can connect to wifi if needed.

Comment: I'm downloading just some text, but my concern are people that has WiFi turned off by default (battery save). I would like "auto connect" capabilities because of those users :)